# Swift get value body from Post Json method

Tags: json, swift, post, alamofire

I try to Post Json with alamofire, which I can, but I need a value that I get from the result of that successful API post. how do I get value from post method JSON in swift? i use Alamofire to make things simple.

```
{
   "phoneNum": "+1234566869",
   "phoneNumTarget": "+2345687960",
   "id": "79999000"
  }
```

so this is the body parameter for my Post JSON,

and this is the result of a successful post JSON

```
{
    "data": {
    "orderId": "79999000",
"uniquesRoomId": 12341414,
"users": [
  {
    "avatar_url": "https:// some web",
    "phone_number": "085858490282",
    "fullname": "BuzzLightyear"
  },
  {
    "avatar_url": "https:// some web",
    "phone_number": "085858490282",
    "fullname": "General Zurg"
  }
],
"chat_name": "user2"
 },
  "message": "room has been successfully created",
  "success": true
  }
```

Now I want to retrieve all the value that I get from that post Json method, how do I do it? do I need to make a struct first like when I want to make get method request for JSON?

*update question

```
let data : [DataClass] = [ ] 

           AF.request(web, method: .post, parameters: chataja,encoder: 
      JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON { (response) in
           switch (response.result) {
            case.success :
           self.data = response
            
            break
```

i try for this and it getting some error

Comment: yes .. you need to do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse this response through Decodable confirmed structs

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - User
struct User: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
    let message: String
    let success: Bool
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let orderID: String
    let uniquesRoomID: Int
    let users: [UserElement]
    let chatName: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case orderID = "orderId"
        case uniquesRoomID = "uniquesRoomId"
        case users
        case chatName = "chat_name"
    }
}

// MARK: - UserElement
struct UserElement: Codable {
    let avatarURL: String
    let phoneNumber, fullname: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case avatarURL = "avatar_url"
        case phoneNumber = "phone_number"
        case fullname
    }
}


AF.request(web, method: .post, parameters: chataja,encoder: 
      JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON { (response) in
           switch (response.result) {
            case .success(let data) :
            let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
```

Comment: ahhh okay and now i just have to make an empty array and just called it from that array? oh and why you make an enum on DataClass and UserElement? why not make enum for all struct?

Comment: so i have to make like this if i wanna grab the orderID ( i update my question)

Comment: `let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: jsonData)`

Comment: but i think that is for get method, im using post method.....

Comment: and you want to decode that json ... using jsonDecoder

Comment: yess but how can i implement that inside my Alamofire func?

Comment: what you are getting in response ?

Comment: well the body of my post method for the params is the response, so i want to get that response......or maybe i use a wrong code for this?